# Missing manifest and package.xml in new project

Tags: vs-code

I've just installed VS Code and am migrating my projects. I don't see an option to delete a project? I created a project without the manifest and package.xml so I can't retrieve the selected metadata I want from the org I'm connected to. I just wanted to delete the project and recreate with a manifest. So, is there an option to delete and start over? I just want to pull down all specific metadata I want into my project. Sorry for the simple question, I'm new to VS Code and learning my way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete the folder and create a new project from VS Code using the Create Project with Manifest option.